# Awk - replacement with seperators

Tags: linux, awk

i wrote this awk-Program

```
awk '{x=$2-5; print $1, x, $3}'
```

which reduces the second number in each line by 5.

This works perfectly fine, when the input is like this: number1 number2 number3 (i.e. seperated by spaces).The output is then number1 number2-5 number3.

Now, how can i extend that program to implement the same functionality if the numbers are seperated by ; instead of spaces - can anyone help me?

For example the input is

```
30;31;32
11;6;5
1;7;10
```

The expected output is then

```
30;26;32
11;1;5
1;2;10
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. Does your input file contain both `;` and `|` separators? Show some example input and the expected output, both formatted as code blocks.

Comment: Look for `FS` and `OFS` in the awk man page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have multiple lines though (wasnt clear from the question, my mistake, sorry) - would this then still be a solution?

Comment: Yes, the number of lines you have has nothing to do with what separates the fields on each line.

Comment: Hi Azes and welcome to the daunting world of awk. Awk is a very powerful, but often underappreciated language. Most documentation is very exhaustive and not practical for direct use. So I suggest having a look at [Awk one-liners explained](https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one) which teaches you awk and explains it. It is not always tuned to your direct need, but it will, for sure, help you on your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close!

You just need to change the `FS` and `OFS` variables and awk will do the rest:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{x=$2-5; print $1, x, $3}' file
30;26;32
11;1;5
1;2;10
```

Read about these variables in the [awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html#index-field-separator-13).

---

As Ed Morton states in comments, you can also use more idiomatic awk if you know the input and output have the same number of fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{$2-=5; print}'
```

Or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{$2-=5} 1'    # the 1 is True and awk reacts to a true by printing
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna be REALLY idiomatic `awk` ::

```
echo '30;31;32
11;6;5
1;7;10' |
```

---

```
awk '($2-=5)_' FS=\; OFS=\;
                                  vs.
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$2-=5} 1'
```

---

```
30;26;32
11;1;5
1;2;10
```

The extra bit about `( )_` is to force a string concat with empty string, so zeros will still get printed out.